# iOS project setup: several apps slightly different between them. Several targets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an iPhone app and now I was asked to create new products (apps) that will use the main code of this app apart from adding some new features. It is not just a PAID/LITE version, we want more than 2 versions. It's a politic app and the new products will be the same app but with a new menu option with some big events (one app for a big event, another one with a different event, and so on).
Apart from this, the different apps (included the original and base one) will also need to work for iPad.

It is not just the content that changes, the code will change also. Different menu, and a new option with the different event depending on which app. The app works with a TabController with 4 options. The first 3 are the same in all the applications, the 4th one gives access to the specific event, with different content and logic.

The theme (mainly colors) of the apps will be also be different.

So I was reading and I got that the solution is to reuse a big part of the code by setting different targets and using macros to execute one or another section depending on the target. But this will lead to a dirty code full of "If-Else". Is there another solution, or a kind of design-pattern to better do this?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Javier.

Comment: Use the same code with different content, why would you even need "if-else" ? Just say goodbye to hardcode and make everything configurable.

Comment: Exactly, read the data from a plist or web site or something and be dynamic.

Comment: It is not just the content that changes, the code will change also. Different menu, and a new option with the different event depending on the app. The event is just an option on the menu. It's a tab menu with 4 options, three of them remain the same thing. The fourth one depends on the event, and give access to a new set of functions-content. 
The theme (mainly colors) of the apps will be also be different.

Comment: To extend on the above, MVC.  The models should take care of the data-side of the app.  Switch the models out when they change.  Edit: just to add a little (comments were added), there is nothing stopping you creating a class, say for example, settings, (perhaps as a singleton), and adding NSAsserts to each method that fetches a settings (ie `getMenuColor`), and subclass the settings class, the NSAsserts will force you to override the methods.

Comment: Make the menu dynamic with options and action driven by model, make a theme (colors, images, layout) part of the model - done, no `if-else`. The only part specific for iOs development here is resources management, you can have `different` files with the same names being used by different targets, for that you store this files separately at filesystem and add required files to the targets, normally you have default resources as well. That is if you want to use only bundle resources, and again binding at the model level will make it better and more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple targets in Xcode can suit your needs very well, you can create multiple targets in Xcode by right clicking on your existing one in the project setting and `Duplicate`.

Then you should add different compiler flag in your duplicated target in order to tell them apart in code. Click your new target and rename it to whatever you want, go to `Build Settings` and search for `Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - Preprocessing`, lets say your second target is named `TargetB`, then `Preprocessor Macros` could be `TARGETB=1`.

In your code you can use `#ifdef` to write different code for different target.

```
#ifdef TARGETB
 //do something for target B
#else
 //do something else
#endif
```

Not only you can use different code in different target, you can also use different resources files too, go to `Build Phases` in each target and check out `Copy Bunle Resources`.