# iPhone and iPad project, submitting to apple

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I finished working on one iPhone app, and my client wants to port it over to iPad. 
Now I created another storyboard for the iPad UI in the same project, and have the iPad UI working and sharing some code with the iPhone code. 
The project has one target, with devices supported as universal.

My question is: My client expects that I present him with two apps, one for iPhone and one for iPad, will this configuration work? 
When I submit this to the app store,  will it know to split it into two apps, or should I just create a separate project for iPad all together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With your current configuration it will upload to the app store as one app, but for users logging in it will display the correct app depending on the device they use on the app store when they search for it.

So depending on if your clients wants two separate APK files or if they want two apps on the apps store:

If the client is requesting two separate apps you will have to split the project, unless there is an easier way that I am not aware of.

You can also explain to the client that with the current configuration the app will have a little plus icon on the app store to indicate that it is a universal app and will work on both devices, which will be determined by the device they use to download and open the app.

If they want to sell the app, again as far as my current knowledge allows, you will need two separate apps as you can not set different prices for it in the current configuration, this statement is under correction. Unless your client wants to sell both iPad and iPhone apps for the same price then you wont have an issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not, because it's the same bundle ID, so in this case, in the App Store you'll have one universal application.

If you want to have two applications, you should create a new Xcode project that supports iPad only.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create different target, one for iphone and the other is for ipad. [You can follow the answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891102/ios-project-setup-several-apps-slightly-different-between-them-several-targets), it is quite good. Because you have 2 different target, you can have different bundle identifiers, specify different AppDelegate, but all the other code could be shared